# How to make a range control in Cocoa touch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to subclass a UISlider so that it displays two knobs, so that I can choose a range ? If not, what would be my options to make such a control ?

Comment: It is definitely possible to do http://vimeo.com/28257365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial that shows you what how to make what you want. [Tutorial](http://buildmobile.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/)